# Tangent planes of torus in general form

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've been having trouble with the following problem.

> Let $R>r>0$. Determine the rectanglular coordinates for the points on the surface
>
> $\begin{cases} x=(R+r\cos(u))\cos(v) \\ y=(R+r\cos(u))\sin(v) \\ z=r\sin(u) \end{cases}$
>
> where the tangent plane is parallel with some coordinate plane.

So far, I have determined the partial derivatives of the parametric equations with respect to $u$ and $v$ gotten
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf r'_u(u,v)&=-r\cos(v)\sin(u)\mathbf i-r\sin(v)\sin(u)\mathbf j+r\cos(u)\mathbf k \\
\mathbf r'_v(u,v)&=-(R+r\cos(u))\sin(v)\mathbf i+(R+r\cos(u))\cos(v)\mathbf j
\end{align}
$$
And simplifying by dividing by the constants $r$ and $(R+r\cos(u))$ in each respective equation:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf r'_u(u,v)&=-\cos(v)\sin(u)\mathbf i-\sin(v)\sin(u)\mathbf j+\cos(u)\mathbf k \\
\mathbf r'_v(u,v)&=-\sin(v)\mathbf i+\cos(v)\mathbf j
\end{align}
$$
By taking the cross product between these tangent vectors I got the following normal vector:
$$
\mathbf n=-\cos(u)\cos(v) \mathbf i -\cos(u)\sin(v) \mathbf j-(\sin(u)\cos^2(v)-\sin(u)\sin^2(v)) \mathbf k
$$

Next I tried the case where the tangent plane is parallel to the xy-plane and tried setting the $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$ components of the normal vector to zero and solve for the according values of $u$ and $v$ yielding an infinite amount of solutions. Since the given parametric surface is a general form of a torus I know that in the case of the xy-plane I should get a circle containing all the respectable points but I'm unable to derive that. Any ideas how to proceed correctly after finding the normal vector and derived the wanted points in the case of xy, xz and yx-planes?

Comment: What are $i, j,k$? Looks like quaternions.

Comment: The unit vectors in the x, y and z direction.

Comment: The third component of the cross product has a sign error in one term; it should be $-(\sin u)\mathbf{k}$. We may then notice the unit normal vector field at $(u, v)$ is minus the geographic parametrization of the sphere with $u$ equal to latitude and $v$ equal to longitude; the rest should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You might be overthinking your next steps. You have found that $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf i=0$, $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf j=0$ result in $\cos u=0$. This equation in a parametric space  $u,v\in(-\pi,\pi]$ has the solution $u=\pm\pi/2$, $v\in(-\pi,\pi]$. Thus, if you fix the value $u$ (e.g. $u=\pi/2$) and consider $v$ as a parameter, you will get a parametric equation for a circle:
$$
\mathbf r = \mathbf iR\cos v + \mathbf j R\sin v + \mathbf k, \qquad v\in(-\pi,\pi]
$$